# jQuery Knob plugin, stop repeating animations (slideDown, slideUp)

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I use [the knob plugin](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob). [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/almostemp/8VC95/1/) It worked greatly till I added the following code to change values on hover (line 327):

```
.bind( "mousemove"
       , function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           s._xy()._mouse(e);
         }
)
```

I need to show this after user clicks (release function) the dial:

```
<div class="tooltip">Tooltip...</div>
```

line 673:

```
$(".dial").knob({
    'release': function ()
    {
        $(".tooltip").slideDown();
        $(".tooltip").delay(1500).slideUp();
    }
});
```

But it keeps repeating after clicking the dial. Slides down and up every 1,5 sec. I want to stop it from repeating. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new handler, `_move`. Since the behavior of `_mouse` is for click events.

```
.bind("mousemove", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    s._xy()._move(e);
})
```

```
this._move = function (e) {
    var v = s.xy2val(e.pageX, e.pageY);

    if (v == s.cv)
      return;

    if (s.cH && (s.cH(v) === false))
      return;

    s.change(v);
    s._draw();
};
```

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/HfFWm/)